# API Gateway to Redirect {client-hostname} to S3 bucket Folder (path overwride)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Was wondering about the integration between S3 and Api-Gateway. S3 is one of the integration you can set up on an HTTP endpoint.

I have a REST API, i'm trying to route traffic from to a specific bucket.

**The idea is to serve multiple static sites from a single bucket.**

The tree is simple: `S3://{ bucket_name }/{ hostname }/{ index.html }.` and when clients GET `{ project1.mydomain.com }` the Gateway will redirect to a file on: `{ bucket_name }/{ hostname }/{ index.html }`.

My research have pointed me that using a server is unavoidable [reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756517/redirecting-aws-api-gateway-to-s3-binary) 
but I still wonder about this integration. Thought to ask to expend my knowledge.

- Is there any way to redirect a path url to a GetObject S3 API request?
- Is there a way to map a header to API Gateway Service integration parameter? maybe by passthrough the request?
- What is the Path override for?
- How to set the bucket path?

Regarding "AWS Subdomain", it is mentioned to leave it blank on the main tutorial i found on this subject ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html)), but couldn't find a proper resource on what it is for, maybe on other services.

Would love to learn more.

< rant>
i'm really struggling with AWS documentation, was wondering if it's just me. I'm an experienced engineer and I feel terrible looking for information in there. I've learned how to list my S3 buckets to the whole world before I've learned how to fetch an item ✌️
< /rant>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hosting multiple sites on S3 bucket serving index.html from directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928994/hosting-multiple-sites-on-s3-bucket-serving-index-html-from-directory-path)

Comment: no, i was asking about API Gateway s3 integration method, not really S3 static hosting of files